# Installing tablesnap

Tags: ubuntu, backup, installation, cassandra

I'm trying to install tablesnap in my Cassandra servers, following what I have found in the [Jeremy Grosser's Github repo tablesnap](https://github.com/JeremyGrosser/tablesnap) but I am not able to do it.

I'm not a system administrator and I'm sure this is related with my ignorance but I have followed the instructions of the "Installation" section and nothing happens. Later I have tried with *aptitude install tablesnap* and it tries to install but I receive a message telling that the package has unmet dependencies:

```
 tablesnap: Depends: python2.6 which is a virtual package.
            Depends: python-pyinotify but it is not going to be installed.
```

The unique option later is to *keep the package at its current version*, thus, not installed. I have checked that I have installed *python2.7* and *pyinotify* is also installed. Does anyone know what can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone finds it useful:

An easy way to solve this is to follow the alternative way Jeremy Grosser offers in Github: copy the code in a file in some folder and execute it from that folder.